# Spring security expression based access control

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to protect my resources. I would like to have an expression like following:

```
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/refugee/{id}").hasRole("BUSINESS");
//Example 
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/refugee/{id}").hasRole("REFUGEE").and().access(principal.id==#id);
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(userService), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

        //Options preflight
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();

        //ACL
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").anonymous();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/refugee/{id}").hasRole("BUSINESS");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/refugee/{id}").hasRole("REFUGEE").and();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "REFUGEE", "BUSINESS");

    }
}
```

And the TokenAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private UserService userService;

    public TokenAuthenticationFilter(UserService userService) {
        super("/");
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "Authorization";
    private final String PARAMETER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "access_token";
    private String token = "";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        this.token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        if ("".equals(this.token) || this.token == null) {
            this.token = request.getParameter(PARAMETER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        }

        //Attempt to authenticate
        Authentication authResult;
        authResult = attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        if (authResult == null) {
             chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another
     * method to authenticate request headers
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken();
        if (userAuthenticationToken == null) {
            //throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Token"));
        }
        return userAuthenticationToken;
    }

    /**
     * authenticate the user based on token, mobile app secret & user agent
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Authentication authUserByToken() {
        Authentication securityToken = null;
        try {
            // TODO - just return null - always fail auth just to test spring setup ok
            User user = userService.findUserByAccessToken(this.token);
            securityToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                    user, null, user.getAuthorites());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Authenticate user by token error: ", e);
        }
        return securityToken;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to write that using a `@PreAuthorize` annotation with expression on the controller handling the request.

Comment: Is there really no other way? Cause i would really like to have everything in one place. The principal.id is already available at this level so it should be possible right?

Comment: The path variable isn't, Spring Security only knows the URL by this stage, nothing has been processed because that is done after the request is processed by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I understand. And there is no way to precompile it? Hmm....can you give me a short tut how to implement it then?

Comment: Just add the annotation to the controller with the expression you want... There are samples in the spring security reference guide of this.